# Align bottom issues

Tags: android

I have a problem about xml file. 
I have 2 relative layouts. First layout is comment and second layout is delete. I want to slide second relative layout when a user touch the screen from right to left to delete comment. Here is my xml codes;

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/commentContainer"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignTop="@id/commentAvatarImage"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/commentAvatarImage"
    android:background="@drawable/rounded_white_bg"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
    android:padding="8dp">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/commentUserName"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:textColor="#f27166"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textSize="14dp"
        tool:text="\@admin" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/commentText"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/commentUserName"
        android:layout_marginRight="40dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:textSize="14dp"
        tool:text="Lorem ipsum" />
</RelativeLayout>


<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/commentTrash"
    android:layout_width="70dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="-41dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignTop="@id/commentContainer"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@id/commentContainer"
    android:background="@color/white">
    <RelativeLayout
        android:background="#FF00"
        android:id="@+id/deleteimg"
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true">
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="35dp"
            android:layout_height="35dp"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:src="@mipmap/comment_trash_icon"/>
    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

When I touch my screen from right to left, sliding is working well. But appearance is not working as I want. 
Here is my appearance;

[image: Here is my appearence]

But actually I want to show fill parent like this;
[image]

When I changed layout_height to fill_parent or match_parent; delete layout fill all the screen height.

But some phones shows correct. Example; Samsung Galaxy3 show correctly, Samsung G7105 doesn't show correctly. What can I do?

Added:
And also their parent layout is;

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tool="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/commentAvatarImage"
    android:layout_width="35dp"
    android:layout_height="35dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp" />

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/commentContainer"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignTop="@id/commentAvatarImage"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/commentAvatarImage"
    android:background="@drawable/rounded_white_bg"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
    android:padding="8dp">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/commentUserName"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:textColor="#f27166"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textSize="14dp"
        tool:text="\@admin" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/commentText"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/commentUserName"
        android:layout_marginRight="40dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:textSize="14dp"
        tool:text="Lorem ipsum" />
</RelativeLayout>
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/commentTrash"
    android:layout_width="70dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="-41dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignTop="@id/commentContainer"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@id/commentContainer"
    android:background="@color/white">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:background="#FF00"
        android:id="@+id/deleteimg"
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true">
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="35dp"
            android:layout_height="35dp"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:src="@mipmap/comment_trash_icon"/>
    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

When I change the code like below;

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/commentTrash"
    android:layout_width="70dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="0dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true">
```

My appearance like this picture;
[image]

Comment: You just has 2 relativelayout?Where is their parent?

Comment: I added parent Relative Layout @tinysunlight

Comment: Try change height of @+id/commentTrash to 0.

Comment: I don't understand this: When I changed layout_height to fill_parent or match_parent; delete layout fill all the screen height. - could you add below screenshot

Comment: I added extra image for you @piotrek1543

Comment: It is not working @tinysunlight I have tried and nothing changed

Comment: add         android:layout_alignParentTop="true" and         android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"  in @+id/deleteimg. And can you set background of @+id/commentTrash to #000000 to location prblem?

Comment: No it is not important. It can be no background @tinysunlight and I have tried, this is not working too. I don't know what can I do

Comment: It's important . It can confitm which layout is wrong,@+id/commentTrash or    @+id/deleteimg.

Comment: delete everything and use only one relative layout.

Comment: For my Samsung Note 2, i also get the same problem. So are there any solutions to solve the issue?

Comment: I haven't solved this issue since I added this question :) @AntoineMurion

Comment: Yes i can't get it done as well. I just set the height with a fixed dp, so it looks normal in "normal text size" but it will have some distortion in "large text size". This is how i deal with it...

Answer (score 0):

> When I change the code like below;
>
> ```
> <RelativeLayout
>     android:id="@+id/commentTrash"
>     android:layout_width="70dp"
>     android:layout_marginRight="0dp"
>     android:layout_height="match_parent"
>     android:layout_alignParentRight="true">
> ```
>
> My appearance like this picture:
>
> [image]

Well, you said to view: "Be so HIGH as you can", so he does it.

I put the xml code and I haven't noticed any problems other than not closed `<RelativeLayout>`

Maybe you put (or me) `<RelativeLayout>` in wrong place :-)

Here's my code (I haven't your drawables, so I used mine):

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                xmlns:tool="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/commentAvatarImage"
        android:layout_width="35dp"
        android:layout_height="35dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:background="@color/colorAccent"/>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/commentContainer"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignTop="@id/commentAvatarImage"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/commentAvatarImage"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:padding="8dp">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/commentUserName"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
            android:textColor="#f27166"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textSize="14dp"
            tool:text="\@admin" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/commentText"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/commentUserName"
            android:layout_marginRight="40dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:textSize="14dp"
            tool:text="Lorem ipsum" />
    </RelativeLayout>


    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/commentTrash"
        android:layout_width="70dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignTop="@id/commentContainer"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@id/commentContainer"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:background="#FF00"
            android:id="@+id/deleteimg"
            android:layout_width="40dp"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true">
            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="35dp"
                android:layout_height="35dp"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"/>
        </RelativeLayout>

    </RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

and it looks:

[image]

If you have question please free to ask

Comment: In preview, there is no problem. But in build, there is a problem like I said and I showed first picture.

Comment: I think you've forgotten about closing `<>`, but ok I would check it on emulators. ANy preferred :-)

Comment: On emulators looks identical.... Replace your code with mine, change drawables, as you had and tell if it not work

Comment: still checking and ... no problem

Comment: It's because different api level have different understand of alignBottom , wrap_content.

Comment: @Aybuke could you tell me  with wich devices with which API you have problem :-) I would than try to fix it ;-)

Comment: Samsung SM-G7105 (Android 4.3, API 18). Only this device has problem. Thank you so much @piotrek1543

Comment: Samsung devices has some issues. Beware :-) No problem :-D

Comment: I hope it is not problem for my boss, too :) @piotrek1543